# Kubernetes Calling multiple values with the same name Helm Charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

We have two networks that suppose to use the sane name ClientApp but different values in the values.yaml file. The network_a works when on a particular network.

For example a user with a particular laptop with network_a can access the application url and can access network-a.co.uk URL. but the issue is that another type of laptop require network_b and we do not want to overrides network_a in the values.yaml file but define also the network_b in order to access application in network-b.co.uk.

deployment.yaml

```
  env:

      - name: ClientApp
        value: {{ .Values.env.network_a }}

// how to define network_b on this deployment template
```

values.yaml

```
  env:

network_a: https://network-a.co.uk
network_b: https://network-b.co.uk
```

Since we can not call the same variables name in the deployment.yaml, how would I put the network_b to use the values from the deployment using the same name ClientApp.

Comment: Ignoring the Kubernetes and Helm setup momentarily, what environment variables need to be passed to the application for this to work?